# Display Blob(pdf) with Webview

Tags: php, android, pdf, webview

Now my PHP can display Blob from MySQL on web browser with `http://localhost/download.php?id=1`

How to display this with webview on android?

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "select * from loancontract where id = '$id'";
    require_once('db_connect.php');
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
    header('content-type: application/pdf');
    echo base64_decode($result['data']);
    mysqli_close($con); 
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: I have edited your question because you are asking about *android development*, not the IDE.